# Кросс-доменный ajax запрос. На сервер приходит пустой $_POST

Tags: ajax, post

Здравствуйте! Было несколько проблем при отправке кросс-доменного запроса. Они решены. И вот в предвкушении ожидаемого результата новая - массив POST  пришёл пустым. Прошу общественность о помощи. Мой код

```
function sendData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://some_domen.com/my_file.php',
            type: "POST", 
            data: {
                'exchange_id': exchange_id,
                'description': description,
                'source_link': wl,
                'job_title': job_title,
                'budget': budget,
            },        
            success: function (data) {

                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error!');
            }
        }); 

    }
```

На сервере код:

```
print_r($_POST);
exit;
```

В ответе приходит

```
array
(

)
```

Comment: Посмотрите параметры запроса, например, через инструменты разработчика в chrome.

Answer (score 1):

curl не обрабатывал в запросе $_POST

Comment: Что-то из вашего "Ответа" ничего не понятно. Нельзя ли объяснить подробнее?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/88719)

Comment: @Denis этот ответ и написал ТС. И видимо это все же является ответом на его вопрос